# querying jdbc using jpql: The column index is out of range: 0, number of columns: 1

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, jsonb

I'm trying to query a postgresql table containing a jdbc column from Java using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotations.

The following query:

```
@Query (value=SELECT o FROM my_table o where trim(o.my_field_1 = ?1)`, nativeQuery = true)
```

fails with:

```
FailedObject: SELECT o FROM my_table o where trim(o.my_field_1) = ? and (o.my_jsonb_field is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') = cast('""' as jsonb)) [java.lang.String]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 0, number of columns: 1.
```

(the extra conjunction `and (o.my_jsonb_field is null ...)` at the end makes no difference)

Question 1. What does this error mean? What am I doing wrong?

Meanwhile, the following non-native query works:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM MyJavaObject o where trim(o.my_field_1) = :my_field_1")
```

However, if I add the jsonb -> operator, it fails:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM MyJavaObject o where trim(o.my_field_1) = :my_field_1 and (o.my_jsonb_field is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') = cast('\"\"' as jsonb))")
```

with:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.my.company.etc.project.model.repo.Repo.getRecordByAB(java.lang.String)! "Encountered "o . my_jsonb_field - >" at character 88, but expected: ["(", ")", "*", "+", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CASE", "COALESCE", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INDEX", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "KEY", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "NULLIF", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "VALUE", "WHERE", <DATE_LITERAL>, <DECIMAL_LITERAL>, <IDENTIFIER>, <INTEGER_LITERAL>, <STRING_LITERAL2>, <STRING_LITERAL>, <TIMESTAMP_LITERAL>, <TIME_LITERAL>]." while parsing JPQL "SELECT o FROM MyJavaObject o where trim(o.my_field_1) = :my_field_1 and (o.my_jsonb_field is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') = cast('""' as jsonb))". See nested stack trace for original parse error. -> [Help 1]
```

Question 2. It appears that jpql doesn't understand ->. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment, but wanted to point out the problematic area in your code/SQL

```
@Query (value=SELECT o FROM my_table o where trim(o.my_field_1 = ?1)`, nativeQuery = true)
```

Declared as native query but use JPA notations like SELECT o and ?1. 
This should be like below

```
@Query (value=SELECT * FROM my_table o where trim(o.my_field_1 = :myFieldFilter), nativeQuery = true)
```

Now second query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM MyJavaObject o where trim(o.my_field_1)
= :my_field_1 and (o.my_jsonb_field is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') = cast('\"\"' as jsonb))")
```

JPA/Spring data does not understand what the operator -> means. This is very specific to Postgres.

Try to use below one

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_table o where trim(o.my_field_1)
    = :my_field_1 and (o.my_jsonb_field is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') is null or (o.my_jsonb_field->'my_jsonb_inner_field') = cast('\"\"' as jsonb))", nativeQuery=true)
```